# How can I (re-)import the exported queue into Handbrake?

Tags: video-conversion, handbrake, json, queue-management

I had a queue in Handbrake, it was pointing at files on my **D-drive** in the *NEW Movies* folder. Now I want to make it point at video files on my **E-drive**, in the *Old Videos* folder.

I exported the queue to a JSON file, I changed all the file paths, but how do I re-import that JSON file, so that it replaces the queue which is already there?